# Verify function is reparameterization

Tags: complex-analysis, parametric, parametrization

Let C be the right half of the circle $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 2\}$. Consider the parameterizations $$ \sigma(t) = 2e^{i\theta}, \frac {-\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac {\pi}{2} $$ and $$ \delta(t)=\sqrt{4-t^2}+it, -2 < t < 2 $$ of C.

Verify the function $\phi: (-2, 2) \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ given by $\phi(t)= \arctan(\frac {t}{\sqrt(4-t^2)})$ is a reparameterization from $\delta$ to $\sigma$.

I've been stuck on this problem for about a day now. I understand how each parameterization describes C in the complex plane, but I'm not really sure how to approach the problem. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\paren}[1]{ \Bigl( #1 \Bigr) }$
\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
\phi(t) = \arctan\paren{\frac{t}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}} &\implies \tan\phi = \frac{t}{\sqrt{4-t^2}} \\  
&\implies 1 + \tan^2\phi = \frac4{4-t^2} \\
&\implies  \cos\phi = \frac{ \sqrt{4 - t^2} }2~,~~\sin\phi = \frac{t}2 \\
\end{aligned} \\
&\implies \delta = \sqrt{4 - t^2} + it = 2(\cos\phi + i \sin\phi) = 2e^{i\phi} = \sigma
\end{align}